# Completing the Square... lol

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the expression:

$$-\frac{(x-\mu_X)^2}{2\sigma_X^2}-\frac{(z-x-\mu_Y)^2}{2\sigma_Y^2}$$

How can I complete the square?

Comment: Easier to do if you factor out $-1/2$.  Is that the "lol" part?

Comment: @hardmath the "lol" part is because this is something I should know how to do by heart at this point of my math career.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is $A^2 + B^2$ for. . .

$\displaystyle A = \frac{(x-\mu_X)}{\sigma _X \sqrt 2 }$

$\displaystyle B = \frac{(z-x-\mu_Y)}{\sigma _Y \sqrt 2 }$

Complete the square to get $(A+B)^2 -2AB$

Then sub in the values of $A$ and $B$

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you Daron!